# JDBC Exception running on AIX (IBM JDK) with JDBC driver version 3.11.1

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are facing issues when using Snowflake JDBC driver 3.11.1 on AIX platforms with IBM JDK. Even basic select queries are failing with below exception. It used to work with earlier version 3.10.3. Did something broke in recent version of JDBC driver?

This is also observed in other big endian platforms like Solaris SPARC and hp ia  (big-endian). Is this a known issue?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Arrow only runs on LittleEndian systems.
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.<init>(UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.java:65)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.<init>(UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.java:50)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocatorL.<init>(PooledByteBufAllocatorL.java:50)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.memory.AllocationManager.<clinit>(AllocationManager.java:53)
```

Comment: From the error-message it's quite clear this product won't support PowerPC (or any big-endian CPU). You should look for alternative  solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake only supports Oracle Java or OpenJDK.

Comment: (Even those couldn't transform PowerPC into little-endian CPU.)

Comment: I understand Snowflake only supports Oracle Java and OpenJDK but this particual exception is observed on other Big Endian Platforms where Oracle JAVA or Open JDK is supported. See the error "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Arrow only runs on LittleEndian systems." Happens from Snowflake JDBC driver 3.11.0